# Java Memory Spaces - Where do they reside?

Tags: java

Does Java memory spaces such as Heap , Metaspace , Stack reside in RAM? Are there any scenarios where these are pushed to disk as well?

Comment: They reside in virtual memory, which the operating system provides. The OS is responsible for determining how vram is backed, which may include swapping pages to disk if and when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java itself doesn't swap on disk as part of its memory management but it can happen if the operating system starts swapping leading to a big impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks @Lothar. In what situations could OS potentially start doing this?

Comment: @PunterVicky: That's a whole question of its own, unrelated to Java. But the short answer is that it depends on your OS.

Comment: And the second short answer is - when the OS needs to give the RAM to another process.